# Basic google map api - adding an overlay question (tag on a GeoPoint)

Tags: android, google-maps

I have the following code ...

HERE  the variable point is a Geopoint object .

I need the current GPS location of my Android , to be updated on this point...

What do I call ? to define the current location on POINT ?!

```
// create a map view  
RelativeLayout linearLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);  
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);  
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);  
    mapView.setStreetView(true);  
    mapController = mapView.getController();  
    mapController.setZoom(14); // Zoom 1 is world view  
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0, new   GeoUpdateHandler());  

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();  
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
    HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);

    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hola, people!", "I am on Earth");
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
        mapController.animateTo(point); 

        //mapController.setCenter(point);



    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the look the following class

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html

You could just use this class to display user's current location on the map.